# Mockito Unit Test with HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito

I wrote code in our Spring Boot 2 application to make a third-party API call with HTTPUrlConnection.

```
public String loginApi(LoginDTO loginDto)
{
    String responseData = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        link = authBaseUrl + loginUrl;
        url = new URL(link);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_TYPE, MEDIA_TYPE);
        String body = getAuth0LoginDto(loginDto);
        // =====================
        // For POST only - START
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END
        // ====================

        try (BufferedReader br = (conn.getResponseCode() >= 400
                ? new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()))
                : new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())))) {

            StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
            String output = null;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                everything.append(output);
            }
            responseData = everything.toString();
        }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new Auth0Exception("Could not create Auth0 Login Body", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Auth0Exception("Error with Login API", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

Now, I am very much used to doing real integration testing, where I make a real call to the web-service and check the results.

I am now being asked to use strictly Mockito, not PowerMockito, not EasyMock, to create mocking tests, and I have never done that before.   My knowledge of Mockito is weak also since I haven't used it in a very long time.

So, I know it has been asked before, and I have really searched on the internet, and I really haven't found a full piece of code as an example.  I see code snippets which leaves me with pieces missing, and I am not knowledgeable enough to add those parts myself.

I know this code actual implementation works fine, and the integration test works fine also.  But, what I have seen before is that some users are being told they need  to change their client code in order to make the mockito tests work.

If I don't get the mocking tests working for HTTPUrlConnection, then I'll be forced to switch over to RestTemplate and Mocking since my co-worker insists we use RestTemplate anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just extract the `HTTPUrlConnection` creation in a new method. Then it is easy to mock.

Comment: I wouldn't know the first thing about what you mean ... I would need an example to copy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since you have asked for a small example which does not make sense but should show the idea:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class App {

  public int status(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
      urlConnection = create(url);
      return urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    } finally {
      if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }

  HttpURLConnection create(URL url) throws IOException {
    return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  }
}
```

---

I would implement this with a spy and as I recommended a mocked `HttpURLConnection`:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AppTest {

  @Spy
  App app;

  @Mock
  HttpURLConnection connection;


  @Test
  void status() throws IOException {
    int expected = 200;
    doReturn(connection).when(app).create(any());
    doReturn(expected).when(connection).getResponseCode();
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.ats");
    int status = app.status(url);

    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, status);
  }
}
```